# Filtering records from a database so it only shows the records with a true value

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

The concept is simple. I have an index page which shows every record in a table but I want to create a drop box which has 2 options(there is a field in my table that has a 1 or 0 value assigned to it), 1 for filtering the records to only show the records that have the 1 and the other to only show records that have the 2. Is there any way to do this?

what I have tried is:

my controller:

```
   public function filter()
    {
        $energys = Energy::all();
        $energys->filter(function ($energys) {
            return $energys->isredundant == '1';
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried recursive function here??

Comment: `Energy::all();` will impact your performance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the where method available in models?

```
$energy = Energy::where('isredundant', true)->get();
```

This should work nicely for what you want to do.

And if you continue having issues, consider casting the 'isredundant' field in your database as a boolean by adding the following to your Energy model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'isredundant' => 'boolean',
];
```

Comment: the issue is that my field isn't a Boolean, It is a tinyInt. so how could i use the where clause there?

Comment: Then it being an integer, just replace "true" with 1 and you should be good to go. And in that case, you wouldn't need the casts part in the model either.

Comment: so just this in the controller and do i need to make a whole new view as well or can the index view still be used?

Comment: You can use any view you desire. You put that in the controller, which will give you a collection of Energy objects that you can loop in the view. Just have to return view('index', ['energy' => $energy]); and should work nicely.

Comment: in the routes though, would I need to create 2 routes? one for one selection and one for the other?

Comment: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.` || this is the error i get